# How do i convert my numpy array to 2D when it should already have 2 dims?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get some columns from my array using

```
[:, x]
```

and my program is complaining that my numpy array isn't 2D but i am pretty sure it is.

```
print(len(inputs))
```

gives me 13715

```
print(len(inputs[x]))
```

gives me 402

```
print(inputs.shape)
```

gives me(13715,)

When i try reshaping

```
inputs.reshape(len(inputs), len(inputs[0]))
```

i get an error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 13715 into shape (13715,402)
```

I know that for each of my each of my 13715 elements, there are 402 sub-elements.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If it was 2D, then `inputs.shape` would return something with two components `(x,y)`. Instead, it appears that your numpy array is filled with regular arrays, which is why the reshape doesn't work.

Comment: @learningthemachine it is unlikely that the array is 2D, becouse in that case print(inputs.shape) should give you (13715,402) but not (13715,)

Comment: What do you mean by `sub-elements`?  What is the `inputs.dtype`?  object or some complicated expression with 402 terms/

Answer (score 1):

When you get a comma like (13715,), it means that you have 13715 rows and that number of columns is not defined, i.e. it's different for different rows. You cannot reshape it, since such operation makes no sense.

You can access each array with the row number, like you did: input[x].

And you can check if each row has the same lenght of 402 like this:

```
bool_check = [len(input[n])!=402 for n in range(len(input))]
sum(bool_check)
```

When an element has not a lenght of 402 you get a True. If you sum then all up, you get a zero only if all elements are 402 long. Else, the sum will tell you how many elements are not 402 long.